# Playing video to multiple chromecasts

Tags: chromecast

I would like to develop a chromecast receiver and sender app which would play the same video to multiple chromecasts and both those videos are in sync. Is there a low level access to video playback and can you use web sockets or other technology to synchronise playback between multiple devices?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control/communicate with two chromecasts using one sender. In other words, two chromecasts will have their own sessions and any synchronization between the two should be done out of band, using, say, a cloud backend or so, within each receiver.